# 3D Matrix traversal Big-O

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity, pseudocode

My attempt for the Big-O of each of these two algorithms..

1)  Algorithm threeD(matrix, n)

// a 3D matrix of size n x n x n

```
layer ← 0 
while (layer < n)
     row ← 0 
     while (row < layer) 
           col ← 0 
           while (col < row) 
               print matrix[layer][row][col] 
               col ← col + 1 
       done 
       row ← row + 1 
  done 
  layer ← layer * 2 
done
```

O((n^2)*log(n)) because the two outer loops are each O(N) and the innermost one seems to be O(log n)*

2)  Algorithm Magic(n)

//Integer, n > 0

```
i ← 0 
while (i < n) 
     j ← 0 
     while (j < power(2,i)) 
          j ← j + 1 
    done 
    i ← i + 1 
done
```

*O(N) for outer loop, O(2^n) for inner? = O(n(2^n))?*

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Algorithm

First of all: This algorithm never terminates due to `layer` is initiated with zero. `layer` is only multipyed by `2` so it will never get bigger than zero, specially not bigger than `n`.
To get this work, you have to start with `layer > 0`.

So lets start with `layer = 1`.

The time-complexity can be written as `T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2`.
You can get this by looking that way: At the end the layer is setted at most to `n`. Then the inner loops do `n^2` steps. Bevor that, the layer was only half that big. So you have to do the n^2 steps on the last rould of the outer loop and all stepps of the round bevor wirtten as `T(n/2)`.

The [masters theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) gets you `Theta(n^2)`.

#### 2. Algorithm

You can just count the steps:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-1) = sum_(i=0)^(n-1)2^i = 2^n-1
```

To get this simplification just take a look at binary numbers: The sum of steps corresponds to a binary number containing only 1's (like `1111 1111`). This number equals `2^n-1`.

So the time complexity is `Theta(2^n)`

Notice: Both your Big-O's are not wrong, there are bette boundings.